# Can't install OS on S6000-ON

Tags: switch, dell, hardware, force10

I have a Dell Networking S6000-ON. I'm trying to install an OS with ONIE but am running into an issue with the EEROM TLV info. Using some of the onie-syseeprom commands came back with this:

```
ONIE-RECOVERY:/ # onie-syseeprom
Notice:  Invalid TLV header found.  Using default contents.
Notice:  Invalid TLV checksum found.  Using default contents.

TlvInfo Header:
   Id String:    TlvInfo
   Version:      1
   Total Length: 6

TLV Name             Code Len Value
-------------------- ---- --- -----
CRC-32               0xFE   4 0xD4431C18
Checksum is valid.

----

ONIE-RECOVERY:/ # onie-syseeprom -s 0x21=S6000
Notice:  Invalid TLV header found.  Using default contents.
Notice:  Invalid TLV checksum found.  Using default contents.
Adding   TLV 0x21: Product Name
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Programming passed.

TlvInfo Header:
   Id String:    TlvInfo
   Version:      1
   Total Length: 13

TLV Name             Code Len Value
-------------------- ---- --- -----
Product Name         0x21   5 S6000
CRC-32               0xFE   4 0xCCF50CE6
Checksum is valid.
```

Two people have spent many hours trying to troubleshoot this, and online searches so far have been in vain.

Comment: I think this is something you will need to work with Dell to fix.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Error i2c_write_2b: No such device or address
Probably means that you got the same cross-faked device:
Chassis shows S6000 revision and have asic for 40gb, but has main board from S4048 device - you can see revision of main board during boot (first stage).

"No such device" means that some program try to access to i2c device. But S6000` soft compiled to use i2c-0 and S4048/S6010 uses i2c-1.